Day Convolution of Sheaves
In Bodil Biering's master's thesis, Conjecture 4.3.3 conjectures that Day convolution of presheaves does not generally preserve sheaf conditions, with an incomplete attempt at a counter-example given. The thesis was written 20 years ago now, has anyone settled this conjecture definitively one way or the other?

Here is a counterexample, though not one arising from a topological monoid. Consider the lattice with 4 objects $P = \{a, b, a \lor b, \top\}$ arranged in the obvious manner. We consider the sheaf subtopos of $\mathsf{Pr}(P)$ which makes $y(a \lor b) \cong y(\top)$ and take $\otimes$ to be the Day convolution induced by $\lor$ on the base category.
We note that $y(a)$ and $y(b)$ are both sheaves for the relevant topology, but $y(a) \otimes y(b) = y(a \lor b)$ is not.
